# Can I use zkSync contracts in other EVM compatible chains?

Tags: polygon, tutorials, zksync, l2, paymaster

I want to deploy a `Paymaster` in Polygon. I have followed [this tutorial](https://era.zksync.io/docs/dev/tutorials/custom-paymaster-tutorial.html) but want to deploy to Mumbai instead of zkSync Testnet.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it is not possible to deploy these contracts in other EVM compatible chains without adapting them.